# LayoutManeger NullPointerException in RecyclerView Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to list song files on the device using RecycleView and get the following error:

```
Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
fragments.LoadFragment.loadTrackData(LoadFragment.kt:50)
fragments.LoadFragment.onCreate(LoadFragment.kt:36)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2949)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:475)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:278)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Line 50 is recycler_view.layoutManager = layoutManager
and line 36 is loadTrackData() calling the function that line 50 is in.

These lines are in the fragment I'm working in:

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.database.Cursor
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.repea.Adapters.TrackListAdapter
import com.example.repea.R
import com.example.repea.TrackData.TrackData
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_load.*

class LoadFragment : Fragment() {

    var trackData:ArrayList<TrackData> = ArrayList()
    var trackListAdapter:TrackListAdapter?=null
    companion object{
        val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 12
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (context?.let { ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(it.applicationContext,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) } !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.requireActivity(),
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
        }else{
            loadTrackData()
        }
    }

    fun loadTrackData(){
        var trackCursor:Cursor? = activity?.applicationContext?.contentResolver?.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,null,null,null)
        while (trackCursor!=null && trackCursor.moveToNext()){
            var trackTitle = trackCursor.getString(trackCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE))
            var trackLength = trackCursor.getString(trackCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION))
            trackData.add(TrackData(trackTitle,trackLength))
        }
        trackListAdapter = TrackListAdapter(trackData)
        var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity?.applicationContext)
        recycler_view.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recycler_view.adapter = trackListAdapter
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE){
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(context?.applicationContext,"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                loadTrackData()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_load, container, false)
    }
}
```

Here's the adapter:

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.repea.R
import com.example.repea.TrackData.TrackData

class TrackListAdapter(TrackData:ArrayList<TrackData>):RecyclerView.Adapter<TrackListAdapter.TrackListViewHolder>() {

    val dtrackData = TrackData

    class TrackListViewHolder(itemView: ActionMenuItemView):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        var titleTV:TextView
        var lengthTV:TextView
        var artTV:ImageView
        init {
            titleTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_title_view)
            lengthTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_length_view)
            artTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.track_art_view)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TrackListViewHolder {
        var view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.load_item,parent,false)
        return TrackListViewHolder(view as ActionMenuItemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TrackListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var data = dtrackData[position]
        var trackName = data.dTrackTitle
        var trackLength = data.dTrackLength
        holder.titleTV.text = trackName
        holder.lengthTV.text = trackLength
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dtrackData.size
    }
}
```

And the widget:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragments.LoadFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What's gone wrong here?

Comment: Remove this line
`var layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity?.applicationContext)`
   And use only this, `recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not bind recycler_view with any view so it gives null, you should reference any view after inflate the layout that hold views.
here an example of using RecyclerView into Fragment class

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)

    view.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    view.recyclerView.adapter = MainAdapter()


    return view
}
```

Comment: Ok, I've moved the if/else that calls loadTrackData(), followed by view.recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity) and view.recycler_view.adapter = TrackListAdapter(trackData), finally return view, into the onCreateView. No errors anymore. I'm still not seeing the list of songs, I just see the blank fragment that the recycle_view is in. I will try to solve this new problem now, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error message saying that your recycler view is null and that because you used it before it created, so you should move the initialization to the `onCreateView` method

Answer (score 0):

my thouts:

```
if (context?.let { ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(it.applicationContext,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) } !=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.requireActivity(),
    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
        PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
}else{
    loadTrackData()
}
```

Try to muve this in `onViewCreated()`
Because your views inst loaded yet, when `onCreate()` is called 
And i dint found where are you initialize  `recycler_view`?